# JCardSim wrong package?

Tags: simulation, javacard, emulation

I try simulating a SmartCard with https://github.com/licel/jcardsim .

The Example Code is like the following

```
// 1. create simulator
CardSimulator simulator = new CardSimulator();

// 2. install applet
AID appletAID = AIDUtil.create("F000000001");
simulator.installApplet(appletAID, HelloWorldApplet.class);

// 3. select applet
simulator.selectApplet(appletAID);

// 4. send APDU
CommandAPDU commandAPDU = new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00);
ResponseAPDU response = simulator.transmitCommand(commandAPDU);

// 5. check response
assertEquals(0x9000, response.getSW());
```

But there is no Package called Cardsimulator in the 2.2.2.jar. Is this code for Verison 3?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/licel/jcardsim/blob/jc2.2.2/README.md) for 2.2.2 README with relevant example code

Comment: @vlp Thanks! helped me out!

Comment: @vlp You might want to post the link to that other readme file and a short summary of its contens as an answer, since this might help others too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Doc for Version 2.2.2 is found here: 
https://github.com/licel/jcardsim/blob/jc2.2.2/README.md

An Excerpt corresponding to the question follows up here:

```
//1. create simulator
JavaxSmartCardInterface simulator = new JavaxSmartCardInterface();
//2. install applet
simulator.installApplet(appletAID, HelloWorldApplet.class);
//3. select applet
simulator.selectApplet(appletAID);
//4. send apdu
ResponseAPDU response = simulator.transmitCommand(new CommandAPDU(0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00));
//5. check response
assertEquals(0x9000, response.getSW());
```